# Splash Screen Problems

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen

I'm coding a splash screen in VB.Net that displays for 3 seconds then shows a login screen. But the splash shows up even when login shows and I have told the splash to hide. Here is my code:

```
    Public Class frmSplash

    Private Sub frmSplash_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Show()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Me.Hide()
        frmLogin.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  For the end-user, there is nothing more annoying than a pointless three-second wait whenever your program is started.  You should only show a splash screen if you're loading the rest of your program in the background.

Comment: In some programs the splash screen is informative, it might alert the user of the program version, the creator of the program, or some other useful information. But I agree, its a bit pointless if you are showing it for the sake of showing it.

Comment: That's what an About dialog is for.

Comment: Which is why it is pointless here. Although, if there is a paid version of the software and a free one, removing the splash on the paid one could be a plus.

Comment: Add a little checkmark on the splash screen: "don't show this screen next time". Then you have the best of both worlds: you inform the user the first time, then he knows, and you don't have to bug him again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Thread.Sleep` in the UI thread will freeze your program.

Also, the Load event fires before the form is shown, so you're calling `Hide` before the form is shown in the first place.

You need to add a Timer component to the form, set its `Interval` to `3000`, and call `Close` in its `Tick` event.  Then, call the timer's `Start` method in the forms `Shown` event.

Comment: It is my understanding that if you place `.Show` in your Load event, it will show before the end of the load event. But perhaps it is better if the asker uses the `Shown` event instead, which is fired after the form is shown.

Comment: You have a point.  However, no Windows messages will be processed during the `Sleep` call, so the form won't be painted, and probably wouldn't be visible at all.

Comment: Alternatively, using Application.DoEvents() could work if you could get it to fire off while it is paused.

Comment: The `Shown` event is fired *after* painting. Which makes it ideal. But I fully agree that using Sleep here is not very suitable as it blocks everything else (and it won't be the first time I saw the Shown event with a partially drawn window). About `DoEvents` that works never while paused (no code is executed then), but when called before `Sleep` it should help.

Comment: **Never** call `Sleep` on the UI thread, even right after `DoEvents`.  (Except maybe `Sleep(1)`)

Answer (score 0):

Your sleep statement is freezing your UI, try running it from another thread.

Comment: The correct thing to do here is use a WinForms timer; it will be more efficient than creating a thread.

Comment: How would I use a timer to do this?

Comment: But assuming he wants to use Sleep still, creating a new thread would be the most efficient way to do it like that. How is it more efficient to use a timer than a thread? I know it is a bit more confusing to use a new thread, but it still works.

Comment: Every thread you create involves a substantial amount of overhead.

Comment: However, you're right that if he really wants to call `Sleep`, creating a thread (or using the ThreadPool) is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! This worked:
Public Class frmSplash

```
Private Sub frmSplash_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SplashTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub SplashTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SplashTimer.Tick
    SplashTimer.Stop()
    frmLogin.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
End Class
```